# Will this closure cause a memory leak?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I know that the following causes a memory leak because `MyClass` and `myClosure` references each other.

```
var MyClass {
    var myVar = 0
    let myClosure: (Int) -> Void

    init() {
        self.myClosure = { x in
            self.myVar = x
        }
    }
}
```

Does the following cause a memory leak as well? Why or why not?

```
var MyClass {
    var myVar = 0

    function myFunc() {
        let myClosure = { x in
            self.myVar = x
        }

        myClosure(0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this will (in practise) not cause memory leaks. `myClosure()` is defined local inside `myFunc()`. When `myClosure(0)` gets called, the closure will be scheduled for execution, and when it's done it will be removed out of memory.

The only problem you have with your code is that `self`, inside your closure, is a strong reference, which might be deallocated by the time the closure is executed. This will result in a bad excess error. Make sure you create a weak reference to self, and use that in your closure.

Comment: Self in this case cannot be deallocated because it is a strong reference. The only case that it can result in exec bad acces is when you use unowned self.

Comment: It actually is better this way, because the deallocation would not start until the function finishes

Answer (score 0):

Declare weak self to avoid memory leak and guard self in order to avoid calling deallocated self

```
func myFunc() {
    let myClosure = { [weak self] x in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        strongSelf.myVar = x
    }

    myClosure(0)
}
```