# Does this closure cause a memory leak in Node.js or Is it a bad programming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, winston

This is not a duplicate of [will-this-closure-cause-a-memory-leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436920/will-this-closure-cause-a-memory-leak), because that is ios/swift and this is javascript/nodejs

For now I intended to use it for debugging only, and keep calling from anywhere like mocha/test, etc.. so it instantly log well formatted debug info/ (complex json objects)  into test folder instead of server console.

Still curious to understand implication because for each call to such function will in turn call `require('winston')`  which I am not sure is a good practice and second I want to ensure about memory leak.

```
exports.debugLog = (() => {
    const winston = require('winston');
    return winston.createLogger({
        level: 'info',
        format: winston.format.json(),
        defaultMeta: {service: 'debug-service'},
        transports: [new winston.transports.File({filename: 'debug.log'})]
    })
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what part of the code you think would cause a memory leak.

It is not a problem to regularly call:

```
const winston = require('winston');
```

Modules are cached so after the module is loaded the first time, subsequent calls to `require()` that same module, just immediately returns the cached exports.  It's fast and not a problem at all.  In your specific case, I would probably write it like this:

```
const winston = require('winston');

exports.debugLog = winston.createLogger({
        level: 'info',
        format: winston.format.json(),
        defaultMeta: {service: 'debug-service'},
        transports: [new winston.transports.File({filename: 'debug.log'})]
});
```

Just because it's simpler to understand.

It isn't clear at all why you were using the extra function wrapper.  `const winston` is local only to this module so no real reason to try to hide it in an IIFE and IMO that wrapper just makes the code a lot more confusing to immediately grok what it's doing.

> Still curious to understand implication because for each call to such function will in turn call require('winston') which I am not sure is a good practice and second I want to ensure about memory leak.

Each call to `debugLog()` will NOT be calling `require('winston')` again.  `debugLog` is assigned the result of `winston.createLogger()` so that's what you're calling repeatedly, not the outer wrapper function you created.  That wrapper function is only executed once at startup.

Comment: you caught it right, require('winston') can be moved outside. Initially I needed a single block, which I can easily copy paste in multiple test file, but later I moved to my utils, but missed the point to move require('winston') outside. and with this I can simply make it a regular function, instead of closure... thanks for catching it.